# Draw curve between two points

Tags: r, matlab, plot, social-graph

I would like to know how people draw the graphs like below.
I have multiple location points. 
I need to connect two locations by a curve. (Not by line) Any idea how to achieve this? In MATLAB I did not find any in-built function.

[image]

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to connect two points with a "line". You're going to have to be much more specific about what the requirements for your curves are.

Comment: This is not an R question, is it?

Comment: @MrFlick Right now I connect 100s of locations by lines. So the graph looks real messy. I need to adjust it to curves so that I could achieve something like the above image. Thanks

Comment: please attempt something

Comment: R or Matlab or do you care? Do you have any example data? Any attempt?

Comment: @Gregor I tried with MATLAB and R, I can only draw matlab plot connecting my points. They are set of straight lines and I need to get some curvy lines like the above one. In above image, the connection between two points is a curve. That is what I want to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of MATLAB (R2015b) you can use the new '[graph and network](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graph-and-network-algorithms.html)' facilities. It offers different kind of [layouts](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.layout.html) maybe you will find some of them appropriate for your problem.

```
s = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7];
t = [2 4 5 3 6 4 7 8 6 8 7 8];
G = graph(s,t);
h = plot(G,'Layout','layered');
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a licensed version of R2015b. Thanks for the tip by the way.